# Entity Framework 6 connection string with DNX

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, dnx

As far as I understand Entity Framework 6, it magically materializes a connection string from app.config/web.config. From DbContext documentation, section remarks:

> If the parameterless DbContext constructor is called from a derived context, then the name of the derived context is used to find a connection string in the app.config or web.config file

for the case of the parameterless constructor, or for the case with a connection string name:

> Instead of using the derived context name, the connection/database name can also be specified explicitly by passing the name to one of the DbContext constructors that takes a string. The name can also be passed in the form "name=myname", in which case the name must be found in the config file or an exception will be thrown.

However, in a DNX project, I don't have an app.config or web.config. How do I specify a connection in Entity Framework 6 in a DNX project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Use Entity Framework 6.x in Asp.Net 5 (MVC 6)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296073/how-to-use-entity-framework-6-x-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6)

Comment: @DavidG That question helps somewhat, but assumes things like a "startup.cs" which is MVC 6 specific. I'm not working on an MVC 6 project.

Comment: What are you working with then?

Comment: @DavidG Currently, a console application (though the question is not specifically aimed at any "project type", and a general answer is more valuable to me; it could just as well have been a Win10 universal app. Asking this question once in general seems more useful than separately for each project type.)

Comment: The linked question only mentions `startup.cs` as a means to get the context into the new DI framework, you don't need to do that.

Comment: The answer there assumes (at least) the installed pre-release packages `Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel` and `Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json`  (which provides `IConfiguration` and `Configuration`) That is (I assume) implicit in an ASP 5 project. These things are not impossible to find out, but a good answer IMO should include such issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is no need for app.config or web.config at least for code first approach. Connection string can be defined in  any configuration file or even without it - hard coded (this is not a good practice).

In ASP.NET 5 with EF6 connection string can be specified in config.json file as usual. This of course assumes loading configuration from json file as @Martijn noticed:

Add two packages to project.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta8",
  "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8"
}
```

Add config.json to your project:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(local);Database=EfExample;Integrated Security=True"
    }
  }
}
```

Load config in Program.cs (this class may not be valid after beta8):

```
[...CODE ...]
using Microsoft.Framework.Configuration;

[...CODE ...]

public class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
     var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(".")
            .AddJsonFile("config.json");
[... CODE ...]
```

Now DbContext can be created with

```
 new ApplicationDbContext(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"])
```

Assuming you already have constructor for `ApplicationDbContext` like this

```
    public ApplicationDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }
```

If you want to know more about configuration in DNX I have blog post about it at: http://bleedingnedge.com/2015/10/15/configuration-providers/

Additional info on different configuration issues with ASP.NET 5 and EF6 can be found here (mostly focused on MVC project though) including configuration for mssql, localdb, postgresql and avoiding other app.config issues: http://bleedingnedge.com/2015/11/01/entity-framework-6-with-asp-net-5/