# LINQ EF7 ASP.NET and many-to-many

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

How i could add records to my database , with relation many-to-many in ASP.NET MVC 6 ?

I tried like that, but it's wrong

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult addpersons(Person pers)
{
    var ourdoc = db.Documents.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Documentid == docselected);
    ourdoc.DocPers.Add(ourdoc);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Content("s");
}
```

Listings of my model files :

DocContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;

namespace TDS_1_ASPNETMVC6.Models
{
    public class DocPer
    {
        public int Documentid { get; set; }
        public Document Document { get; set; }

        public int Personid { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }
    }

    public class DocContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<DocPer>()
                .HasKey(t => new   
                {
                    t.Documentid,
                    t.Personid
                });


            modelBuilder.Entity<DocPer>()
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Document) 
                .WithMany(p => p.DocPers)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.Documentid);

            modelBuilder.Entity<DocPer>()
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Person)
                .WithMany(t => t.DocPers)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.Personid);
        }

    }

}
```

Documents.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace TDS_1_ASPNETMVC6.Models
{
    public class Document
    {
        public int Documentid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Props { get; set; }


        public List<DocPer> DocPers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Person.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace TDS_1_ASPNETMVC6.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Personid { get; set; }
        public string Iname { get; set; }
        public string Fname { get; set; }
        public string Oname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }



        public List<DocPer> DocPers { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your controller is not checking for null; what if `var ourdoc = db.Documents.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Documentid == docselected);` is null? So check for null first :)

Also `ourdoc.DocPers.Add(ourdoc);` must be changed to `ourdoc.DocPers.Add(new DocPer {Person = person});`

Second, to create a many-to-many I suggest you to remove the `DocPer` table and map it "behind", like this:

```
public class Document
{
    public Document()
    {
        Persons = new List<Person>();
    }

    public int Documentid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Props { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        Documents = new List<Document>();
    }

    public int Personid { get; set; }
    public string Iname { get; set; }
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    public string Oname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }

}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
                .HasMany<Person>(s => s.Persons)
                .WithMany(c => c.Documents)
                .Map(cs =>
                {
                    cs.MapLeftKey("Documentid");
                    cs.MapRightKey("Personid");
                    cs.ToTable("DocPer");
                });
}
```

DocPer table will be managed by the EF without exposing it. Check [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) site for more details. This guide will apply to EF6 only, not EF7 (which does not support many-to-many yet, for that support check [this](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#many-to-many) link). BTW, EF7 is still is not stable yet, so is possibile that this support will be offered in the future, but no one knows yet.

Comment: It's show error on method  .WithMany , in .HasMany no .WithMany method .

  modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
             .HasMany<Person>(s => s.Persons)
             .WithMany(c => c.Documents)
             .Map(cs =>
             {
                 cs.MapLeftKey("Documentid");
                 cs.MapRightKey("Personid");
                 cs.ToTable("DocPer");
             });

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem; can you be a little more specific? I tried this code and looks right. Have you checked the link at bottom of the post?

Comment: Sorry, my fault; looks like EF7 does not support many-to-many yet, too soon. Two options: follow this guide here https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#many-to-many or (best, EF7 is not stable yet) use EF6 for the moment (follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296073/how-to-use-entity-framework-6-x-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6)

Comment: It's okey. But how i must make , a request to my many-to-many tables , to read, add and edit ?
Like below is not working : 

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult addpersons(Person pers)
{
    var ourdoc = db.Documents.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Documentid == docselected);
    ourdoc.DocPers.Add(ourdoc);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Content("s");
}

Comment: I updated the answer. ourdoc.DocPers.Add(ourdoc); must be changed to ourdoc.DocPers.Add(new DocPer {Person = person});

Comment: If ourdoc is null you will get this kind of error (I don't speak Russian, so I guess, at least)! You can't use .FirstOrDefault() and not check for null :) Are you sure "ourdoc" returns an object? Did you initialized the DocPers collection? You have to do it manually if it's null with a new List<DocPer>();

Comment: And still )) sorry for my English, but i want to solve this, what's wrong i do?  My variables are not Null, you can see it below 
http://s018.radikal.ru/i513/1603/22/c901f8ac47a8.png

Comment: Actually, docpers.DocPers looks null from what I see here. Did you first created an empty list with ourdoc.DocPers = new List<DocPers>() ? Than you can add your item with ourdoc.DocPers.Add( ecc. ecc.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!!
It's code work great.

         var ourdoc = db.Documents.FirstOrDefault();
            ourdoc.DocPers = new List<DocPer>();
            var peeer = db.Persons.FirstOrDefault();

            if (ourdoc != null && peeer !=null)
            {
                
                ourdoc.DocPers.Add(new DocPer { Person = peeer });
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return Content("s");